# Swift does type Any include AnyObject

Tags: swift

From what I've understood

- Any can represent instance of any type
- AnyObject only represent instance from any **class** type

So I thought that any instance of AnyObject can also be cast as Any.
Until I found this issue:

```
var data: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...)
if let dictionary = data as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
  #this code is never called

} else if let dictionary = data as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
  #Surprisingly This block is called
}
```

How come the first block is never called whereas the second works.
I know that AnyObject doesn't extend Any but I was pretty sure that i could cast any instance of AnyObject as Any.

Does someone have any clue on the matter or point me where I am wrong? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about your syntax in the if statement, which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Yep there were mistakes in the if statement, corrected. Thanks